# JS не вешать событие на элемент с определенным ИД

Tags: javascript, jquery

как можно на Jqery\js не брать элементы с определенным ид

например

```
   var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),select,textarea');
```

т.е. не учитываются скрытые поля а можно написать что-то вроде

```
   var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"],[id="ware"]),select,textarea');
```

Comment: Вас логика И или ИЛИ интересует? Если И, то без запятой должно работать, если ИЛИ, то дублировать, заменив `type="hidden"` на `id="ware"`

Comment: нужно ИЛИ. но вот в примере код не работает

Comment: "продублировать" - имелось ввиду продублировать не часть, а все: `var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),input:not([id="ware"]),select,textarea');`

Comment: так тоже не сработало

Comment: а, ну да, `input:not([id="ware"])` выберет те input'ы, где id не равен ware, но тогда выбирает скрытые инпуты и наоборот, а `input:not([type="hidden"][id="ware"])` выберет только скрытые инпуты, у которых id равен ware. А вам надо "особенное" ИЛИ - чтобы type="hidden" и type="hidden" не выбирались? А просто отфильтровать уже после выборки нельзя? Или назначить определенный класс тем элементам, которые должны выбираться, тогда выборка вообще простой будет

Comment: котлеты отдельно мухи отдельно. хиден это одна песня, а элемент с ид другая. в принципе мне нужно чтобы при селекте он блюр не работал. пока сделал так  `var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),select,textarea');
    var $onlyinput = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),textarea');`

Comment: но и для элемента с указаным ид хотелось бы узнать условие

Comment: `id` на странице должен присутствовать в единственном виде. А вообще примерно так: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/n2srbmn6/)

Comment: `<select id="ware" name="ware" onchange="window.location.search = "template=" + this.value;">` при `var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),select:not("#ware"),select,textarea');` срабатывает `$inputs.on('keydown',`